# Recurrent Neural Network Training and Test Sets

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I'm constructing an rNN optimized by a GA. This happens to be my first project in this area, so  I got confused by certain things. It would be great if someone could help me out with understanding them better.

First of all, training and test data sets look quite different for ANNs and rNNs. If, for example, I'm predicting time series, I have a set of n observations. How do I go about using it? I mean, do I need to have n input neurons or 1 input neuron? How to I calculate an error? Every generation or every k'th generation? Do I have to average over k (i.e. the fitness function is going to be mean squared error over k generations).

After n generations I reach the end of the sample, do I need to replicate it a number of times? In such case, what do I use as a test set, the same sample or a different one?

I understand it's a lot of questions, but I'd be grateful if someone could help me out with at least some of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that when you say you're trying to predict a time series you mean that you have a series of data and you're trying to predict the next value. If this is the case, you only want one input node, because you only have one piece of data at a time to base the prediction off of (if I'm making an incorrect assumption and you're actually trying to make one classification based off of the entire time series, then you would want n input nodes).

If you're using the term "generation" in the genetic algorithm sense, I don't really see a way to avoid calculating error every generation, as you'll need to evaluate the fitness of all members of the population in every generation in order to generate the next generation. However, because you talk about reaching the end of the sample after a certain number of generations, it sounds like you might actually be talking about running the neural net on successive points in the time series. It does seem like you would want some sort of error metric that takes into account the error at each point in the time series. The easiest thing to do would probably be to just sum them up as you go. Dividing by k at the end to get an average would probably be more intuitive (the average error on a given estimation is something we tend to think about more than summed error), but since k is a constant it shouldn't actually matter which one you use for your fitness function, as long as you're consistent.

If my understanding of your problem thus far is correct, you're basically evaluating fitness of each candidate neural net in your population by running the entire time series of data through it and keeping track of the error. Since the whole thing is your fitness function, you need to run it for each candidate structure in each generation. Thus, this sample could be construed as your training set. In order to evaluate success more generally, you would need to have a different time series to use as a test set.

Hope that helps! Let me know if I misunderstood your question or if any part of that is unclear.

Comment: Thanks, I already got most of it. I have 1 input x(t) and 1 output x(t+1). Now my question is, if I run the entire time series x to get the error value of the weight vector (species in a GA), what should I use as a test set? The exactly same time series? Or should I run the weights through some subset of time series (training set)?

Comment: Another thing I'm thinking of is delay window, i.e. feed x(t),x(t+1),x(t+2) and the target output is for x(t+3), here the delay window is 3.

Comment: If you only have one time series, then you'll need to designate a portion of it (80% is conventional) to be your training set and not use the other 20% in calculating fitness for the GA. You can then test on the remaining 20%. If you use the same data for both, you won't know if your algorithm actually learned anything that generalizes beyond that exact series.

A delay window sounds interesting. Obviously, you would need to give the neural net a number of input nodes equal to the delay window size (plus one for a bias node).

Comment: Thanks, that's roughly what I thought

Answer (score 0):

The ANN work describe :
[image]

your input data (X1,X2,...) going to the box and calculating with chosen w then the box show the output as our class. in this case you only have binary data, but if you want set another data like 2,3,... and other you must use this formula to set your output range between 0 and 1 :

[image]

Initialize the weights (w0, w1, …, wk) then Adjust the weights in such a way that the output of ANN is consistent with class labels of training examples : 
[image]

Find the weights wi’s that minimize the above objective function

so you can use the ANN for many of data.

for example the result of the data can be like this ( show in percent):
[image]

Comment: I don't think so: RNN feedforward process is different from ANN's